# PySpark: How to group a column as a list when joining two spark dataframes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to join the following spark dataframes on Name:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("Mark", 68), ("John", 59), ("Mary", 49)], ['Name', 'Weight'])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(31, "Mark"), (32, "Mark"), (41, "John"), (42, "John"), (43, "John")],[ 'Age', 'Name'])
```

but I want the result to be the following dataframe:

```
df3 = spark.createDataFrame([([31, 32], "Mark", 68), ([41, 42, 43], "John", 59), `(None, "Mary", 49)],[ 'Age', 'Name', 'Weight'])
```

Comment: Group df2 by a key to collect values as list then equi join with df1 on the same key. Can you try that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collect_list` from the module `pyspark.sql.functions`. It collects all the values of a given column related to a given key. If you want a list with unique elements use `collect_set`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("Mark", 68), ("John", 59), ("Mary", 49)], ['Name', 'Weight'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(31, "Mark"), (32, "Mark"), (41, "John"), (42, "John"), (43, "John")],[ 'Age', 'Name'])

df2_grouped = df.groupBy("Name").agg(F.collect_list(F.col("Age")).alias("Age"))
df_joined = df2_grouped.join(df1, "Name", "outer")

df_joined.show()
```

Results:

```
+----+------------+------+
|Name|         Age|Weight|
+----+------------+------+
|Mary|        null|    49|
|Mark|    [32, 31]|    68|
|John|[42, 43, 41]|    59|
+----+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A DataFrame is equivalent to a relational table in Spark SQL.  You can groupBy, join, then select.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sc = SparkContext()
sql = SQLContext(sc)

df1 = sql.createDataFrame([("Mark", 68), ("John", 59), ("Mary", 49)], ['Name', \
'Weight'])

df2 = sql.createDataFrame([(31, "Mark"), (32, "Mark"), (41, "John"), (42, "John\
"), (43, "John")],[ 'Age', 'Name'])

grouped = df2.groupBy(['Name']).agg(collect_list("Age").alias('age_list'))

joined_df = df1.join(grouped, df1.Name == grouped.Name, 'left_outer')
print(joined_df.select(grouped.age_list, df1.Name, df1.Weight).collect())
```

Result

```
[Row(age_list=None, Name=u'Mary', Weight=49), Row(age_list=[31, 32], Name=u'Mark', Weight=68), Row(age_list=[41, 42, 43], Name=u'John', Weight=59)]
```